# Rewrite URL with SKU

Tags: url, sku

i want to rewrite the url of product  from
www.example.com/product-name.html
To
www.example.com/SKU.html

Someone can help me ?I am beginner of magento.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to rewrite existing products and not implement any programatic change to the default way Magento creates URL keys then see below.

For Magento 1.x:

http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/url-rewriting

For Magento 2.x:

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-write-redirect-301-rules-for-magento-2.html

Comment: Thank you ,but i have more than 2500 existing products,maybe need to do some programing.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [this 301 import module:](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-extension-url-rewrite-importer/)

You would export all your products and change the column heads of the sku column to be what that module needs for the new URL and then import to bulk rewrite the URLs.